# If $A \cap B = \{x \in \mathbf{R^3} : 2x_1+2x_2-2x_3=0\}$. Then find $\dim A\cap W.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $A \cap B = \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} : 2x_1+2x_2-2x_3=0\}$. Then find $\dim A\cap B.$

This implies that $x_3 = x_1+x_2$ from where I get that $2x_1+2x_2-2(x_1+x_2)=0$ and $x_1(2,0,-2)+x_2(2,0,-2)$ spans $A \cap W$, but these vectors are clearly linearly dependent and don't form a basis form $A\cap B$ from where I could deduce the dimension. Is the another basis that I'm not seeing here? Is it the case that $A\cap B = \{0\}$?

Comment: Why do you think they don't form a basis? It seems $A\cap B = \textrm{span}( (1,0,1) , (0,1,1) )$, since the condition $2x_1 + 2x_2 - 2x_3 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1 + x_2 = x_3$. So the points in $A\cap B$ look like $(a,b, a+b)$, and the two vectors above span, and are manifestly linearly independent.

Comment: $(2,0,-2)$ and $(2,0,-2)$ are not linearly independent?

Comment: Notice that $x_1+x_2-x_3=0$ represents the plane of the vectors orthogonal to $(1,1,-1)$ so it cannot be composed of only $\mathbf 0$, you found a solution (other than zero) to the equation yourself.

Comment: I see. The dimension would be then $\dim A \cap B = 2$.

Comment: Yes, the set has dimention 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need a clearer algorithm for finding vectors that span a given subspace.

Consider that:

$$
x_1= x_1 \\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\,x_2= \,\;\;\;\;\;\;\; x_2\\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\,x_3=x_1+x_2
$$

So two vectors spanning the set are $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. They're not parallel so they must be linearly independent but you could offer a formal argument by assuming that $$c_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0$$

And then proving that the two coordinates must be zero.

PS.

Given that the set represents a plane of the vectors that are orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ it couldn't have had $\text{dim} =1$, planes have two degrees of freedom.